# Обработка изображений в Java

Tags: java, graphics

Есть такая задача, передать цвета одного изображения другому, я хочу реализовать это на Java, но опыта работы в этом направлении нет.
Есть готовый алгоритм, и есть много примеров на С++(OpenCV), Python и Matlab, и там все реализуется довольно легко, вопрос вот в чем: обработка изображений в Java на хорошем уровне находиться? Или лучше не лезть туда? И можно ли реализовать эту задачу? Если можно, то нужно работать с классом RGBFilter?
Знаю, что закроете вопрос, но мне нужна любая подсказка.

Comment: зачем java? если на других языках вам все понятно, то используйте их.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, в C++ и Python используется OpenCV, что облегчяет задачу, я же хочу из интереса и любопытства решить эту задачу на Java, без использования каких-либо библиотек, чтобы понять алгоритм, и как правило узнать что-то новое